# Using a JavaScript index variable to access a ViewBag array item

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to access a global javascript variable in order to pass it as part of the data to my ajax function.  Struggling with how to do it because `imageIndex` does not exist in the current context.
Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var imageIndex = 0;
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var imageIndex = 0;

            getImage();

            function getImage() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: '@Url.Action( "GetImage", "Tally" )',
                    data: { imageName: '@(ViewBag.images[imageIndex])', contractID: '@(ViewBag.contractId)' },
                    //dataType: "image/jpeg;base64",
                    success: function (data) {
                        console.log(data);
                        $('#scanImage').attr('src', 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + data.myImage);
                        $("#imageName").val('@(ViewBag.image)');
                        imageIndex++;
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        console.log("got error");
                    }
                });
            }
        });

    </script>
```

Comment: why did you initialize imageindex twice?

Comment: You have two `imageIndex` variables in your code, and actually *both* of them are in scope in your `$.ajax` call?

Comment: What is this `@(…)` syntax? I suspect you're mixing up client- and serverside processing here.

Comment: @Bergi ASP.Net MVC + Razor, it's legitimate. The issue is that it doesn't like concatenation so I'm not sure how to include a variable to access the ViewBag images array by index.

Comment: When I couldn't get the imageIndex to work initially, I tried adding a second declaration inside the document.ready to see if that would fix anything.  That is why I had 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The Issue(s)**

**1.** Remove one of your `imageIndex` initializations from the top. For all intents and purposes I'd say it really doesn't matter which one in your case.

**2.** `imageIndex` is being included as part of `imageName` *as a string*, rather than the variable's value.

---

**The Tricky Part**

Razor won't let us simply concatenate the variable as we normally would by doing something like:

```
imageName: '@(ViewBag.images[' + imageIndex + '])'
```

Because we're including a single quote within the server-side `@`, C# will tell you that you have an overflowing literal.

---

**The Solution**

Instead, we'll need to populate a normal javascript array *from* the `ViewBag.images` array.

```
   var imageArray = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(@ViewBag.images));
// var imageArray = ["image1", "image2", "image3"];
```

From there, we can now use `imageArray[imageIndex]` to retrieve the value we're looking for.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var imageIndex = 0;

    //Convert our ViewBag.images into a JS array
    var imageArray = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(@ViewBag.images));
    getImage();

    function getImage() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: '@Url.Action( "GetImage", "Tally" )',
            data: { imageName: imageArray[imageIndex], contractID: '@(ViewBag.contractId)' },
            //dataType: "image/jpeg;base64",
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                $('#scanImage').attr('src', 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + data.myImage);
                $("#imageName").val('@(ViewBag.image)');
                imageIndex++;
            },
            error: function () {
                console.log("got error");
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: I removed one.  I now have `'@(ViewBag.images['+imageIndex+'])'` and am getting: `Error 6 Too many characters in character literal`

Comment: Hmm, this is most likely C# being upset that we're using a single quote. Let me take a deeper look into this, will be a bit more tricky than I originally thought.

Comment: @dmikester1 Please see my edit and let me know if this works.

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you much!

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I think you are getting it wrong here:

```
imageName: '@(ViewBag.images[imageIndex])'
```

try: `imageName: '@(ViewBag.images[' + imageIndex + '])'`

also, why are you declaring variables twice?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var imageIndex = 0; //this
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var imageIndex = 0; //and this?
....
```